# Howto increment a hex number within a file

Tags: awk, hex, decimal, increment

A common CI build type issue, I have a header that has a version number I want to increment before a build.

so test.h

```
#define VERSION_PROJECT_MAJOR   01
#define VERSION_PROJECT_MINOR   69
#define VERSION_VENDOR          2
```

Needs to get a 6A for the minor version.

The environment is DOS/WIN with gnu utils, so I think awk is the way to go but I cannot quite spin it. The version the build system has does not do inplace, but I can live with that.

I have a pretty decent one-liner so far;

```
awk  "/#define VERSION_PROJECT_MINOR/{$0=$1 \" \" $2 \"   \" (strtonum(\"0x\" $3)+1)}1;" test.h
```

This sets the version number to 106, how do I make it output hex???

Comment: why 6A? 69(DEC)=45(HEX) or?

Comment: @kent 0x69 is 105 in decimal

Comment: @fedorqui ok, I see, the 69 is HEX.

Comment: Enclose your scripts in single quotes, never in double quotes. Among other things that'll mean you don't have to escape `$`s and `"`s inside your script.

Comment: What I used in the end, for the sake of anyone looking in future...

awk --non-decimal-data "/#define VERSION_PROJECT_MINOR/ {$3=strtonum(\"0x\" $3); $3=sprintf(\"  %X\",$3+1)}1" test.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using GNU awk's [`non-decimal-data` flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal-Data.html):

Just convert to decimal, perform the addition and then convert back to hexadecimal:

```
awk --non-decimal-data '/MINOR/ {
           $3=sprintf("%d", "0x"$3); $3=sprintf("%x",$3+1)
          }
          1' file
```

With your file:

```
$ awk --non-decimal-data '/MINOR/ {$3=sprintf("%d", "0x"$3); $3=sprintf("%x",$3+1)}1' file
#define VERSION_PROJECT_MAJOR   01
#define VERSION_PROJECT_MINOR 6a
#define VERSION_VENDOR          2
```

This uses the fact that `%x` in `printf` returns the decimal value of a hexa.

```
$ awk --non-decimal-data 'BEGIN{printf "%d\n", 0x69}'
105
```

Comment: @EdMorton sure! Note [the GNU awk guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal-Data.html) mentions on this _CAUTION: Use of this option is not recommended. It can break old programs very badly. Instead, use the strtonum() function to convert your data (see String Functions). This makes your programs easier to write and easier to read, and leads to less surprising results._

Comment: Thanks guys, I combined the answer given with the strtonum advice. It refused to accept single quotes so I went with doubles and escapes.

Comment: @ChrisAaaaa good to read that! Feel free to share your solution so we can all learn from it as well